# What's the difference between these 'Java Version'

Tags: java, maven

There are several place in eclipse which I can set up java version:

```
1. Java Build Path - Libraries
2. Java Compiler 
3. pom.xml - java.version
4. Run as -> Run configuration -> Runtime JRE
```

I'm confused about the difference, so what's the difference ?

Comment: The first three are about the build settings. They should be aligned (ideally all taken from `pom.xml`).  The last one is the runtime environment (which can be different).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Java Build Path**  - The build class path is a list of paths visible to the compiler when building the project.

**Java Compiler** - This would be either the compiler included in the IDE or one from the specified JDK. [Read more on how an IDE uses one.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/java-compiler.html)

**pom.xml - java.version** - You can specify the version to be used by maven to build the project. e.g 1.7 for building the code using Java7 . This would overwrite the previous two for a maven framework based project.

*Run as -> Run configuration -> Runtime JRE* eventually is the 
java version required to run your application.

As already pointed by @Thilo, you shall make sure the first three are pointing to the same(*jdk*) path while the last one can vary as you run your application.

Comment: and the last one (runtime environment) will definitely vary when you ship the finished application to other people (unless you can get them to use a certain JDK version)

Answer (score 0):

As their names suggest:

1. Java Build Path - Libraries -  You are setting the java version to build your application
2. Java Compiler - You are setting the java version to compile your application
3. pom.xml - java.version - You are setting the java version to (build,compile) your application if you happen to use maven
4. Run as -> Run configuration -> Runtime JRE - You are setting the java version used in running your application,i.e the run time environment

Answer (score 0):

Item 2 is the java version that eclipse will use to compile your projects, and if I remember correctly, libraries in item 1 are based on this version.

Item 3: in pom.xml you can set the version used for maven to compile it, overwriting eclipse's config (or used if you build outside eclipse).

Item 4: I don't use this very often but I believe you can set a different version when running a program.